# facebook graph API message_tags is not working

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, tagging

I have created an app in fb and add **taggable friends** in items from app setting (status & Review). and using this js code for tagging but not working for me. please help me to solve this issue. basically i **want to tag a friend while creating post.**

```
FB.ui({
    method: 'stream.publish',
    name: 'aaaa',
    link: 'http://google.com',

    message: 'aaaaaaa',
    message_tags: [{
        "id": 655423781,
        "name": "mobi"
    }],
    caption: "like this, you tag friends",
    description: 'post description'
},

function(response) {
    if (response && response.post_id) {
        alert(response.post_id);
    } else {
        alert(0);
    }
});
```

Comment: How is it not working? For example, is it not doing anything or is it producing an error and, if an error, what error?

Comment: not tagging user what i have mentioned in message_tags[]

Comment: You can not tag other users in normal wall posts. `taggable_friends` is for tagging/mentioning users in Open Graph Stories only.

Comment: @CBroe What do you mean with normal wall posts? As I understand we can use the api to publish posts in the feed, in groups and pages. The tags are not available for users feed?

Comment: Did you find a solution? I'm interested too.